# Nginx fail on Docker deployment to Amazon

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy .net asp web api application in Docker container to Amazon via elasticbeanstalk, but here is what I got:

```
ERROR: Failed to start nginx, abort deployment
ERROR: [Instance: i-ecf0d365] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "172.17.0.2:5000/tcp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Image is here: https://hub.docker.com/r/wedkarz/awsm8-api/

### Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:latest

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]
```

### elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf file

```
upstream docker {
    server 172.17.0.2:5000/tcp;
    keepalive 256;
}
```

Comment: Error message suggests that you have a spurious `/tcp` in your `nginx` configuration file, either on an `upstream server` directive or an `xxx_pass` directive.

Comment: I have updated question with conf file? Where this nginx configuration came from? was it included in aspnet image? or docker put this for whatever reason?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems to have used `5000/tcp` as the port, rather than the correct value which should be `5000`.

Comment: @RichardSmith you were right! I changed Dockerfile to EXPOSE 5000 and now it works :)

Comment: @RichardSmith nice catch. can you please submit this as the formal answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message `nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "172.17.0.2:5000/tcp"` shows an `upstream server` parameter with the spurious characters `/tcp` following the port number. See [upstream module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server).

@Fishman confirmed that the erroneous parameter appeared within the `nginx` configuration file, and that this file was generated from the Dockerfile, and that the problem was corrected by changing the value of the `EXPOSE` parameter (within the Dockerfile) from `5000/tcp` to `5000`.